# Connecting to MSSQL server using RJDBC in Rapache

Tags: apache, r, jdbc, rapache

I have a problem connecting to an MSSQL server using rApache. I use the addon-package "RJDBC" to connect to this server. In the R-Console I can connect fine and access the server but when I try to connect trough rApache (on my test website) it fails and I get an error. This is the line when it fails.

```
 drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqldserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","/var/www/sqljdbc/sqljdbc4.jar")
```

This is the error displayed in the browser: Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

In the apache error log all I get is

[Tue Jun 26 12:55:32 2012] [error] [client 10.21.2.79] rApache Notice!

Thanks for your help,

Comment: you need additional parameters, check out this post to get the connection going: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326879/