# RJDBC can't read table from MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, r, mssql-jdbc, rjdbc

I'm running R locally and the database sits on a MS SQL server remotely.

I do my prep work:

```
require(RJDBC)
# initialize the driver 
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", "C:/files/sqljdbc4.jar") 
# establish the connection 
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:sqlserver://DBserverName.example.com;instanceName=myINS;databaseName=myDB", "myUser", "myPass")
```

Then I check if I can read the header of some tables:

```
dbListFields(conn,"table1")
```

Works. Next I try to read the full table:

```
dbReadTable(conn,"table1")
```

Fails with:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM table1 (Invalid object name 'table1'.)
```

Doing it the SQL way also fails:

```
sqlText <- paste("SELECT FROM \"table1\" ")
queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlText)
```

Fails with:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM "table1"  (Invalid object name 'table1'.)
```

and without quotes:

```
sqlText <- paste("SELECT FROM table1 ")
queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlText)
```

Fails with:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM table1  (Invalid object name 'table1'.)
```

Any idea why this fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To actually read from the table it needs to be specified with its hierarchical **prefix**. The following worked:

```
dbReadTable(conn,"groupingA.table1")
```

Likewise works:

```
sqlText <- paste("SELECT FROM groupingA.table1 ")
queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, sqlText)
```

Comment: how do you determine what that prefix is? Mine did not work using the database name as the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Give the exact name of the table that includes database name , if exist dbo and table name for example :

```
queryResults <- dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM [dbname].[dbo].[tablename]")
```